# A more effective way to list things from Firebase with Angularfire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am working on a web based character creation tool for a D&D style RPG. I am trying my hardest to list "Race" from my firebase DB. The current structure looks like:

```
|-ironkingdoms
|--Race
|---Dwarf
|-----RaceName:Dwarf
|-----Starting Attribuites
|------PHY:7
|------STR:8
|------POI:5
|---Human
|-----RaceName:Human
|-----Starting Attributes
|------PHY:6
|------STR:7
|------POI:4
```

You get the idea... I put the "RaceName" in there because I could not for the life of me figure out how to get it to list all the children of "Race". Here is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GhQn1e9bdCdAnKNsJZ1K?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
        <head>
            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
            <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            Data:
            <div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.RaceName}}</div>
            <p>
            <div>Data loaded: {{dataLoaded}}</div>
            <p>
            Messages:
            <div ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg}}</div>
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myapp', ['firebase']);

                app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) {
                  var ref = new Firebase("https://<yourFirebase>.firebaseio.com/Race");
                  $scope.data = $firebase(ref);
                  $scope.dataLoaded = "Not yet!";
                  $scope.messages = [];

                  $scope.data.$on("loaded", function() {
                    var keys = $scope.data.$getIndex();
                    ["Race"].forEach( function(element) {
                      $scope.messages.push("Test for " + element + ": " + (keys.indexOf(element) !== -1));
                    });
                    $scope.dataLoaded = "Yep!";
                  })
                });     
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So far it seems to work OK when I use "RaceName" but anytime I take the /Race off of the path and try to list the children of "race" it seems to not work. The little DB knowledge I have comes from a SQL background. So this is a little confusing to me. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Adding some more to my question. Not sure it will get answered but I would rather not start a new question just for this.

How can I use ng-repeat in a situation like the following:

```
    <table>(Work in progress) Table with Rows of AttributeType with columns of AttributeGroup
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Attribute Set</th>
      <th>Starting Attributes</th>
      <th>Hero Limit</th>
      <th>Veteran Limit</th>
      <th>Epic Limit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-model="refAttributes">
    <tr>
      <td>AGI</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].AGI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].AGI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].AGI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].AGI}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ARC</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].ARC}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].ARC}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].ARC}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].ARC}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INT</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].INT}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].INT}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].INT}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].INT}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PER</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].PER}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].PER}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].PER}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].PER}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PHY</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].PHY}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].PHY}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].PHY}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].PHY}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>POI</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].POI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].POI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].POI}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].POI}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PRW</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].PRW}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].PRW}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].PRW}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].PRW}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SPD</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].SPD}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].SPD}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].SPD}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].SPD}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STR</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Starting Attributes'].STR}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Hero Limit'].STR}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Veteran Limit'].STR}}</td>
      <td>{{refAttributes['Epic Limit'].STR}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 9 should become

```
<div ng-repeat="(raceName, item) in data">{{raceName}}</div>
```

ngRepeat directive supports getting the key along with the value in the above way.

Answer (score 3):

Dat Chu's answer will certainly get you the race name, but I'd like to propose an alternative related to how you structure your data. Depending on your app's eventual size this may or may not be important - if you're only ever going to have a small amount of data under the /Race location then it's not a big deal.

Your current structure will require downloading all of your Race data including sub-attributes in order to list out all of the Races. Another option would be to store a simple list of races at another location like ironkingsdoms.firebaseio.com/AvailableRaces/ which would just have a simple array of race names. This would allow you to grab just that list, display it to your users, and then they could select a race and then you could construct a query against /Race/{racename}/ and only pull down that data.

Again - if you only have a few races and the overall object size is small then it may not be bad to download it all upfront (Firebase streams it to you anyway). But if you end up in a situation where you have hundreds of races and each race has a bunch of data underneath it then you could be chewing away at your firebase bandwidth unnecessarily.

Firebase posted a nice write-up about denormalization that you may find interesting @ https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: That is good to know. I am not very good at denormalizing data just yet. My current issue is that if I add a race with the attributes I would rather not have to update a list elsewhere with the name of that race. I want to have one true source. It seems hard with denormalizing in that you seem to almost HAVE to duplicate some data. I just haven't caught up to the learning curve yet as this is my first venture into flat data like this.

Comment: You duplicate data in order to speed things up. For example, caching the results of a db query in memory is a form of data duplication and if you aren't careful with your cache invalidation things can get out of sync. Well crafted services backed by unit tests go a long way in managing the risks of data getting out of sync

Comment: I ran into a similar concern, imagine if your dataset gets to be 50MB, do you want your user to have to download the entire 50MB before really doing anything? (massive slowdown) the goal of firebase is speed, so I have to admit this might be a better approach.

Comment: I agree with @onaclov2000 as I had similar issues where some of my data included images, the data took an age to load because it was pulling in about 20MB of data, not good for mobile apps. So denormalisation is a good approach.